# serializer.DictField does not save to database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have this model:

```
class x(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    y = models.ManyToManyField(Y, related_name='y', db_table='x_y',
                                     blank=False,null=False)
```

and this serializer:

```
class Serializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = models.x
       fields = '__all__'
```

when I post data to this model I need to set this fields:

```
'name':['some name'],'y':['1','2']
```

this will make a row in database x with:

### id | name

1  | some name

and two row in database x_y with:

### id| x_id | y_id

### 1 | 1    | 1

2 | 1    | 2

the problem is that front end dose not send me 'name' and 'y' ,but send me 'name' and 'y[]', so in order to get data I needed to add this to my serializer class:

```
y= serializers.DictField(child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=2))
```

but the result is that no data will save in x_y table.I dont know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

One issue that stands out to me is that you're using a `DictField` to handle a list of integers.

Presuming the integers are actually the primary key of your Y model, have you tried using `y = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)`?  This seems like what you would be after.

Comment: yes I did it. in this case that you said the incoming request when I call request.data is > <QueryDict {['y' :['1','2']}> ,but when I get request.data from my angular front end result is this >  <QueryDict {['y[]' :['1','2']}> and if I dont use DictFile and use Primary relatedField it raise error that there is no value for y.

Comment: My other problem is that why Json from front end turns to QUery dict when I write requst.data?